# How to post a JavaScript variable into a MySQL database using AJAX and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I know this question gets asked a lot, but I went through all the similar questions on here and I still can't fix my script. The Insert query works, but the "Name" shows up as 0 in the database.
My JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function SendData() 
{
var Name = "Ballsack"; //The name I am trying to get into database.
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        else 
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+Name,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        alert("The query was send");

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="button" value="Send" onClick="SendData();"><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My PHP (getuser.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','jack','*****','VLA');
if (!$con) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$query = "INSERT INTO TrafficRegisterDetails
(Name,Surname,Age,Address,TrafficRegNumb,NumberPlate)
VALUES('$q','Sak','12','Kernma','1212','blahblah')";
$result = $con->query($query);
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: ".$con->error);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First fix your security issue for sql injection. Then you don't need html code in your getuser.php file. Are those file on the same server ? maybe you should have a look at CORS and headers to make an API. Then why parsing the name you are sending as int ? Read php manual to get some informations about what are the functions you are using doing.

Comment: I know I know :) This was just to unserstand where I went wrong, but I found it, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access JavaScript variables value in php to store in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806126/access-javascript-variables-value-in-php-to-store-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of `$q = intval($_GET['q']);`.
It change your string to 0.
See [PHP intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for the reply sir. Could you suggest what $q should be set to then?

Comment: @JaunSamtin You can use [PHP filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) to solve sql injection problems.

Comment: @JaunSamtin Please set correct answer as Accepted Answer to others can use your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an intval:

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
```

That's why "Ballsack" turns to 0.

Comment: I see, thank you. I was unaware of the meaning of intval.. I get it